# How to pass object-variables to test cases in RobotFramework?

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework

Here's what's going on (generically) with my python-based test.

```
==============================================================================
***Settings***

Variables       variable_file.py
Library         library.py

***Test Cases***

A Test Case
      myTest      ${some string}       [I want to pass an object here]

=============================================================================
```

At the end, I want to pass an actual class object which has been defined inside my variable file. I've looked far and wide without finding a way to pass anything beyond a string or a list. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 2):

By default, ${variable} are strings, but it can also contain objects.
And you can pass it to keywords as argument.

Take a simple example like that:

```
${mydict} =  Create Dictionary  a  1  b  2
```

=> Then you have ${mydict} = {'a': '1', 'b': '2'}

And then you can call a keyword with your object as argument. For example:

```
Dictionary Should Contain Key  ${mydict}  a
```

I am using that kind of thing to test a REST API that sends me JSON. I store JSON objects in Robot variable and check the results by exploring the content of the dict. I explained it a little bit in a [blog post](http://laurent.bristiel.com/robot-framework-rest-and-json/).

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate object variables in variable files as stated in [User guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-files)
Here is a generic example

Variable file:

```
#var_file.py:
class foo(object):
    a = "foo"
    b = "bar"

MY_VAR = foo()
MY_SECOND_VAR = foo
```

Test case file:

```
#var_file.txt
*** Test cases ***
log variables
    log    ${MY VAR.a}
    log    ${MY VAR.b}
```

Execute using:

```
pybot -V var_file.py var_file.txt
```