# Robot Framework - pass library function as parameter

Tags: python, robotframework

I got a simple test case which I can't get to work in my `testLib.py`. I have:

```
def free(arg):
  print "found arg \"{0}\"".format(arg)


class testLib:

  def free_run(self,func,arg):
    print "this is free test"
    func(arg)

  def member_func(self,arg):
    print "mem func arg={0}".format(arg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  x = testLib();
  x.free_run(free,"hello world")
  x.free_run(x.member_func,"free - mem test")
```

Then in Robot Framework test file mytest.robot I have:

```
*** Setting ***
Library         MainLib.py  
Library         testLib.py

*** Test Cases ***

test2
  free run       free           "testing free run"
  self run       member_func    "testing self run"
```

When I run the framework, I get:

```
==============================================================================
test2                                                                 | FAIL |
TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable
```

Any idea how to pass the member and free function to the library?

Comment: Robot is a keyword testing framework (not a scripting language) so it likes to pass values, lists and dictionaries around, but not objects.Maybe [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178984/how-to-pass-object-variables-to-test-cases-in-robotframework) will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing built-in to robot that you can do. From robot's perspective, "free" is just a string. You need to convert that to an actual function object. I can think of a couple different ways to do this.

If `free` were a keyword, you could define `free_run` like this:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
def free_run(self,func,arg):
  print "this is free test"
  BuiltIn().run_keyword(func, arg)
```

Another option would be to look up the function name in the result returned from [globals()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals), if it's safe to assume that `func` refers to a global function:

```
def free_run(self,func_name,arg):
    print "this is free test"
    func = globals()[func_name]
    func(arg)
```